# ROS Ubuntu 14.04 on vmware

Tags: ros

I am trying to setup `ROS electric` on Ubuntu 14.04 on VMware but get an error message from `sudo apt-get install ros-electric-desktop-full`:

```
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libcheese-gtk23 : Depends: libclutter-gtk-1.0-0 (>= 0.91.8) but it is not going to be installed
                                     Depends: libcogl15 (>= 1.15.8) but it is not going to be installed
 libcheese7 : Depends: libclutter-gst-2.0-0 (>= 0.10.0) but it is not going to be installed
                            Depends: gstreamer1.0-clutter but it is not going to be installed
 libclutter-1.0-0 : Depends: libcogl-pango15 (>= 1.15.8) but it is not going to be installed
                                        Depends: libcogl15 (>= 1.15.8) but it is not going to be installed
 ros-electric-desktop-full : Depends: ros-electric-ros-tutorials (= 0.2.6-s1336562333~oneiric) but it is not going to be installed
                                                         Depends: ros-electric-nodelet-core (= 1.6.2-s1336531052~oneiric) but it is not going to be installed
                                                         Depends: ros-electric-eigen (= 1.6.0-s1336530551~oneiric) but it is not going to be installed
                                                         Depends: ros-electric-geometry-tutorials (= 0.1.3-s1336562524~oneiric) but it is not going to be installed
                                                         Depends: ros-electric-orocos-kinematics-dynamics (= 0.2.3-s1336530597~oneiric) but it is not going to be installed
                                                         Depends: ros-electric-filters (= 1.6.0-s1336531164~oneiric) but it is not going to be installed
                                                         Depends: ros-electric-slam-gmapping (= 1.2.5-s1336543727~oneiric) but it is not going to be installed
                                                         Depends: ros-electric-ros (= 1.6.9-s1336528271~oneiric) but it is not going to be installed
                                                         Depends: ros-electric-stage (= 1.4.1-s1336556336~oneiric) but it is not going to be installed
                                                         Depends: ros-electric-documentation (= 1.4.3-s1336548893~oneiric) but it is not going to be installed
                                                         Depends: ros-electric-visualization (= 1.6.7-s1338543665~oneiric) but it is not going to be installed
                                                         Depends: ros-electric-vision-opencv (= 1.6.13-s1336531637~oneiric) but it is not going to be installed
                                                         Depends: ros-electric-perception-pcl (= 1.0.2-s1336532338~oneiric) but it is not going to be installed
                                                         Depends: ros-electric-geometry-experimental (= 0.2.2-s1336544234~oneiric) but it is not going to be installed
                                                         Depends: ros-electric-robot-model-visualization (= 0.1.2-s1336572168~oneiric) but it is not going to be installed
                                                         Depends: ros-electric-rx (= 1.6.1-s1336538058~oneiric) but it is not going to be installed
                                                         Depends: ros-electric-image-pipeline (= 1.6.4-s1336532075~oneiric) but it is not going to be installed
                                                         Depends: ros-electric-simulator-gazebo (= 1.4.15-s1338549736~oneiric) but it is not going to be installed
                                                         Depends: ros-electric-diagnostics-monitors (= 1.4.3-s1336547062~oneiric) but it is not going to be installed
                                                         Depends: ros-electric-simulator-stage (= 1.4.0-s1336557410~oneiric) but it is not going to be installed
                                                         Depends: ros-electric-common-rosdeps (= 1.0.2-s1336530376~oneiric) but it is not going to be installed
                                                         Depends: ros-electric-geometry-visualization (= 0.1.1-s1336588763~oneiric) but it is not going to be installed
                                                         Depends: ros-electric-image-common (= 1.6.1-s1336531478~oneiric) but it is not going to be installed
                                                         Depends: ros-electric-bond-core (= 1.6.1-s1336530969~oneiric) but it is not going to be installed
                                                         Depends: ros-electric-common-tutorials (= 0.1.2-s1336589157~oneiric) but it is not going to be installed
                                                         Depends: ros-electric-ros-comm (= 1.6.7-s1336529499~oneiric) but it is not going to be installed
                                                         Depends: ros-electric-visualization-common (= 1.6.3-s1338486485~oneiric) but it is not going to be installed
                                                         Depends: ros-electric-physics-ode (= 1.6.1-s1336537616~oneiric) but it is not going to be installed
                                                         Depends: ros-electric-assimp (= 0.1.1-s1336534582~oneiric) but it is not going to be installed
                                                         Depends: ros-electric-driver-common (= 1.2.4-s1336530279~oneiric) but it is not going to be installed
                                                         Depends: ros-electric-executive-smach (= 1.0.4-s1336544144~oneiric) but it is not going to be installed
                                                         Depends: ros-electric-common-msgs (= 1.6.0-s1336529945~oneiric) but it is not going to be installed
                                                         Depends: ros-electric-image-transport-plugins (= 1.4.2-s1336531748~oneiric) but it is not going to be installed
                                                         Depends: ros-electric-xacro (= 1.6.0-s1336531255~oneiric) but it is not going to be installed
                                                         Depends: ros-electric-robot-model (= 1.6.4-s1336534646~oneiric) but it is not going to be installed
                                                         Depends: ros-electric-bullet (= 2.76.5-s1336530427~oneiric) but it is not going to be installed
                                                         Depends: ros-electric-visualization-tutorials (= 0.4.0-s1338571715~oneiric) but it is not going to be installed
                                                         Depends: ros-electric-geometry (= 1.6.1-s1336530789~oneiric) but it is not going to be installed
                                                         Depends: ros-electric-pluginlib (= 1.6.0-s1336530068~oneiric) but it is not going to be installed
                                                         Depends: ros-electric-executive-smach-visualization (= 1.0.2-s1336563281~oneiric) but it is not going to be installed
                                                         Depends: ros-electric-laser-pipeline (= 1.2.1-s1336536850~oneiric) but it is not going to be installed
                                                         Depends: ros-electric-robot-model-tutorials (= 0.1.2-s1336578371~oneiric) but it is not going to be installed
                                                         Depends: ros-electric-common (= 1.6.1-s1336531318~oneiric) but it is not going to be installed
                                                         Depends: ros-electric-diagnostics (= 1.6.4-s1336530145~oneiric) but it is not going to be installed
                                                         Depends: ros-electric-navigation (= 1.6.5-s1336537141~oneiric) but it is not going to be installed
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
root@ubuntu:/home/ggg/y-ppa-manager#
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Electric relies on different versions of core libraries. Although [this question](http://answers.ros.org/question/155631/install-ros-hydro-ubuntu-1404/) is about hydro. The same issue applies to you.

> ROS depends on specific versions of system libraries such as Boost, and the versions of those libraries that are available on 12.04 and 14.04 are different enough to make installing the 12.04 binaries on 14.04 very difficult.

If the ROS version doesn't matter, ubuntu 14 binaries work for indigo and up

*Edit*

There is a thread of someone building electric to work on 12.04 [here](http://answers.ros.org/question/37981/electric-running-under-ubuntu-1204-precise-pangolin-lts/#40063), but there's a bunch of custom configuration that needs to happen to build it.

Comment: so if i want things to work out of the box from here: http://wiki.ros.org/electric/Installation/Ubuntu, i should find `ubuntu 11.10`?

Comment: I think so, just follow the [Supported platforms page](http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0003.html)